# Is "fatah" an alternative spelling of "fatwa"?

Tags: orthography, transliteration

I've occasionally seen "fatah" being used instead of "fatwa" to mean Islamic religious ruling. For example, from [Fear and Loathing of Sharks in Western Australia](http://www.seashepherd.org.au/commentary-and-editorials/2012/10/01/fear-and-loathing-of-sharks-in-western-australia-564) by Paul Watson (in an article which elsewhere complained about halal slaughter):

> This week, this same premier of Western Australia issued a
>   shark-hating **Fatah**, calling for their total annihilation.

You can find more examples by googling for "issued a fatah" or "a fatah against".

When I looked up "fatah" in onelook.com, all the entries referred to the Palestinian militant organisation [Fatah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatah).

Is "fatah" a valid alternative transliteration of the Arabic word typically transliterated as "fatwa", or is it a mistaken use of the wrong word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your hunch is right sir: "Fatah" is a mistaken use of the wrong word.Fatwa *is* the word for Islamic religious ruling.For more explanation please see:

http://www.islamicsupremecouncil.org/understanding-islam/legal-rulings/44-what-is-a-fatwa.html